# How to create stub, that throws exception on all calls in Rhino mocks?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, stub

Is it possible with Rhino Mocks to create a stub, that throws exception for all calls?

```
public interface IMyIF
{
    // Some methods
}

[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
        IMyIF stb = mocks.Stub<IMyIF>();

        // Somehow set stb to throw some exception on every method call
        // without knowing all the methods and overloads in IMyIF interface

        // use stb to test something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var stb = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<IMyIF>();
```

Comment: Good enough for me now, but what if I want to throw specific exception?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible with Rhino Mocks.

Comment: Why create stub then? Pass `null` instead

Comment: There is different behavior of code under test for null value.

Answer (score 1):

Very strange requirement. What are you trying to test? If you are testing that method `Bar` of interface `IFoo` throws some exception when it is called by your test class, then just set this expectation on method Bar. Do not test all methods at once.

This will focus your test on one specific interaction between sut and dependency (I'd go this way):

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMyIF>();
mock.Expect(m => m.Foo()).Throw(new MyCustomException());
sut.Exercise(mock);
```

This will throw ExpectationViolationException:

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<IMyIF>();
sut.Exercise(mock);
```

This will throw NullreferenceException:

```
sut.Exercise(null);
```

Also you can create class `MyIFStub` inherited from `IMyIF`. Right-click on interface name and select *Implement interface*. Visual Studio will generate subbed members of interface, which will throw NotImplementedException. You can change stub implementation, if you need:

```
public class MyIFStub : IMyIF
{    
    public void Foo()
    {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // other members
}
```

Comment: I'm testing MyClassUnderTest, that depends on IMyIF. I do not want to depend on what overload of method in IMyIf is actually called (it can change, but the meaning of the test does not), I want to test, that when MethodUnderTest of MyClassUnderTest is called and the IMyIF, that the function depends on, fails, MethodUnderTest recovers from that situation.

Comment: But you don't expect, that MethodUnderTest will call any random member of IMyIF, do you?

Comment: Actually I do not care which one will be called. All the methods do the same thing, only differences are some extra informational arguments, that, for this test, does not matter.